# Can the Bible become an idol?

Tags: bible, idolatry

I was wondering if there is a danger that the Bible could become an idol and I might indirectly worship it without realizing it.

We say the Bible is the word of God. It is divinely inspired so putting my trust in what is written in Bible is good. But what if I put my trust solely in Bible? Would that be committing idolatry - assigning the attributes of God to the Bible and making the Bible the only authority in my life? Let's say by wrong interpretation of some verses I can fail to do good, harm another or even cause disunity among my friends.

So my question is: Is there a danger of making the Bible an idol? If not, what could it be that would make it happen?

Look at the image below:

[image]

Idolatry definition:

The worship of a physical object as God.

Immoderate attachment or devotion to something.

I'm interested in any denomination perspective. Please back-up your answer with your church teaching.

Comment: There is certainly precedent.  It would not at all be an exaggeration to say that, in Jesus's day, the Jewish leaders had so fetishized and embellished the Law of Moses that worship of God's words had displaced worship of God!

Comment: The Bible is the repository of the Word of God. As Mason Wheeler points out, we can fall into a kind of idolatry with respect to it, though I would add that this idolatry probably is more about aggrandizing our own interpretations or embellishments (as the Pharisees did) than unduly honoring the actual Word of God.

Comment: I wonder if most of Christians do commit idolatry because of such a disunity among them.

Comment: Good question, but unfortunately this looks primarily opinion based. There are varying definitions in Christendom of what an idol is.

Comment: @LCIII, well then the whole Christianity is opinion based?

Comment: @Grasper Yes, Christians are aware that we do this to ourselves. Google [biblliolatry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bibliolatry)

Comment: @YuletideGeek, and nobody ever address this problem?

Comment: @Grasper I'm sure somebody somewhere does.

Comment: @LCIII, here now? lol

Comment: I don't understand the connection between biblolatry and disunity.

Comment: @curiousdannii, one word of God(bible) = one church. It can't be one God and thousands of churches. HS unites, satan disunites...

Comment: @Grasper Sure, but that doesn't seem related to this question.

Comment: Its more likely that the Pauline Epistles by themselves will become an idol than that the Bible as a whole will.

Answer (score 5):

The term for this tendency to "over-elevate" Scripture is [bibliolatry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bibliolatry#In_Christianity).  It is typically a perjorative term in which one identifies oneself as having overemphasized the letter of the law over the Spirit.

Typically the most common usage adheres to evangelicals and Protestants.  This [article from Westminster](http://wscal.edu/resource-center/resource/is-bibliolatry-possible), for example, questions whether or not bibliolatry is possible.  Its conclusion states:

> No, what some may call bibliolatry is not always- indeed, is rarely such. Let us truly love the Lord our God with all our hearts and worship him only. But "to reverently esteem" the Book, "the heavenliness of the matter, the efficacy of the doctrine, the majesty of the style, the consent of all the parts, the scope of the whole...is to give all glory to God."

John Piper, a prominent evangelical, says much the same in [this video](http://www.desiringgod.org/interviews/if-you-could-say-one-thing-to-the-next-generation-of-church-leaders-what-would-it-be). He says:

> I'm a Calvinist, and I'm not going to go there, because I believe I got my Calvinism from the Bible. If I didn't get it from the Bible, then I don't want people to be Calvinists. So it seems better to say, "Hold fast to the Bible. Base everything on the Bible. If you are going to criticize somebody, criticize them from the Bible. If you are going to affirm somebody, affirm them from the Bible. If you are going to do a strategy, do it from the Bible. Be a Bible saturated people." That's what will make for long term staying power for the gospel.
>
> I know this is going to be called bibliolatry, and people will say, "You worship the Bible, not God." Bologna on that. People who reject the Bible for God become idolaters.

Both of these seem to be admissions that the perception of idolatry is real, but adherents have good reasons if they have fallen into the error.

Generally speaking, most tenets of Christianity rely on [spiritual tension](http://en.fgulen.com/questions-and-answers/1116-what-is-the-purpose-of-spiritual-tension), a concept not unrelated to the [via media or golden mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_mean_%28philosophy%29). Even a good thing, held too closely, can be bad. Its just that people falling into the error usually think they have the right balance.

Comment: this isn't good answer now. I was more asking about committing idolatry with the bible towards my life and not faith. I can have good faith but bad works because of wrong perspective on the bible...

Comment: It feels like you are voting on "truth" or whether or not you agree with it, moreso than if the information is being presented. I was trying to give examples of the usage of the term and concept

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Bible itself tells us the "letter killeth" but the "spirit" giveth life. If our physical nature (carnal mind) only sees the physical letters and carnal interpretations, then idolatry is in the making. If we look back into the Old Covenant which has been fulfilled in purpose, and we continue to not see Jesus as the Messiah ushering in his Kingdom. If we refuse the teachings of Grace and continue in the carnal Law. If we, like "Lots Wife" look back at the old city which is under judgment, we too are at risk of drying up from the inside out. If the image we form in our minds from the words of the Bible have more physical characteristics than spiritual, then we are guilty of "missing the mark." For these reasons and more I believe we can make the Bible an Idol in subtle ways. Remember, the Serpent is more subtle...

Comment: what about if Christians cause disunity among Christians because of bible? Doesn't that make the bible to be a subject to idolatry?

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. Please see [What this site is about](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1379/what-christianity-stackexchange-is-and-more-importantly-what-it-isnt/) and [How this site is different](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites/1809#1809) to help you learn how the site works. Also see the [help] and take the [tour] to learn the site functions. I hope to see you post again soon.

Answer (score -1):

From the tone of your question and the fact that you are aware of risks if any, you are very unlikely to commit idolatry with the Bible. You may quite properly regard it as inspired writing and as a guide to God's expectation of you, but then it is God you are worshipping, not the Bible.

You could be worshipping the Bible if you attribute to it what you have been taught to attribute to God alone. For example, you have been taught that God is infallible. If you insist that the Bible itself is infallible and that any evidence to the contrary must be reinterpreted in order to eliminate the error or contradiction, you could arguably be committing bibliolatry, "immoderate attachment or devotion to [the Bible]."

You ask, in comment, what if Christians cause disunity among Christians because of Bible; doesn't that make the Bible to be a subject to idolatry? If two groups or denominations interpret the Bible differently and agree to disagree on their interpretations, no harm is done. If each side insists that the Bible, and therefore their interpretations of the Bible, are infallible, they may argue intemperately and could become guilty of immoderate devotion to what is only a physical thing. I would ask, have they never heard of prayer?

Comment: that's exactly what is happening what you wrote in your second last sentence. It means that all Christians who came from reformation are 'bibliolateries'. They think they have their own truth and their interpretation is infallible. Otherwise they would not split from the original church but rather try to help her from the within, changing their hearts and hearts of other.

Comment: @Grasper I'm afraid I would disagree with you there. Believing that faith should be based on the Bible is very different from idolatry. In any case, Luther tried to help the Catholic Church from within until he was excommunicated.

Comment: well, because he was doing it in a wrong way. St. Francis tried it too and he ended up still in union...

Comment: @Grasper In answering this question, I assumed you were specifically interested in biblical idolatry. If you were interested in 'proving' the Catholic Church superior to Protestant ones, you should have said so. I see nothing of biblical idolatry in mainstream Protestantism (and I am not a Protestant).

Comment: sola scriptura isn't biblical idolatry? I think it is... Placing the bible over God. But don't get me wrong. I'm not saying word of God, which is bible over God. What I mean placing my own or churches interpretation over God. And that's what protestants do...How do I know? Look at the disunity in Protestantism...